# Best solution for a cross-platform (open-source) shared calendar

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, calendar, collaboration

Today, almost nobody is only using one device actively. I for example, use a CentOS workstation, Ubuntu Notebook, Win 7 Gaming PC, Win 10 remote desktop and an iOS Phone. Therefore, I am looking for calendar solutions that sync cross-plattform across any device. Currently, I am using Evolution Mail on linux and iCalendar on iOS to sync my googlemail and work-mail calendars.

I am unsatisfied with that in various ways:

1. I want to share my calendar (or parts for it; or a separate calendar) with my boyfriend. I might also want to share my work calendar with colleagues for collaboration. I am not sure that this is supported by Outlook or Googlemail - attached calendars.
2. I want to ditch googlemail for a more open-source / FLOSS alternative, because I would rather not share every appointment with a big data company.
3. For my taste, the calendar-view of evolution-mail is a bit chaotic and cluttered, and I'd like something with an easily comprehensible look. This might of course be decoupled based on whether we only look at calendar services or calendar apps.

So I am here to look for wome alternatives. What are you guys using to not miss your appointments, no matter where you are and what device you use?

Comment: For your second bullet point, have a look at OwnCloud. It has a Calendar element that works fine and exports everything neatly as CalDAV. - Now for a client that works, looks nice, speaks CalDAV and is not on the cloud: I came looking here for this too.